# Linux dictionaries

Tags: linux, dictionary, n-gram

I need files containing wordlist for every possible language available. I searched for that and found that [ftp.gnu.org](ftp://ftp.gnu.org) hosts `aspell` directory that contains lots of dictionaries  but as i extracted them i did not found any raw files with words data. I need this for generating n-grams and possibly recognize the language in a particular text.

Answer (score 1):

The file */usr/share/dict/british-english* is contained in the package *wbritish* and is in turn the *Ispell English Word List* from [Kevin's Word List Page](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) where also other dictionaries are available for download.

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=3732e80b128d016f&resid=3732E80B128D016F!3584&id=3732E80B128D016F%213584 which is exactly what i was looking for.